# Error in retrieving data which contains null from Cassandra Database using Spark/Cassandra connector

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark

I want to retrieve data from Cassandra using Cassandra/spark Connector in java. Some of values in table are null. I use

```
JavaRDD<String> rdd = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("test", "Sportman", Sportman.class)
            .map(new org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function<Sportman, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(Sportman person) throws Exception {
                    return person.toString();
                }
            });
```

I got this error when trying to run the program.

TypeConversionException: Failed to convert column accomplished of table test.Sportman to java.lang.Boolean: null

The I define Sportman class like this:

```
public static class Sportman implements Serializable{
    private UUID rowid;
    private Boolean accomplished;


    public Sportman(){}

    public UUID getRowid() {
        return rowid;
    }

    public void setRowid(UUID rowid) {
        this.rowid = rowid;
    }

    public Boolean getAccomplished() {
        return accomplished;
    }

    public void setAccomplished(Boolean accomplished) {

            this.accomplished = accomplished;

    }
```

I don't know how to change get method to fix this error. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is has been fixed recently.